# After login to captive portal,user can access router page and also ssh to router in openwrt

Tags: networking, ssh, openwrt, captiveportal, coovachilli

I am having TP-Link WR841Nv11 router and I upgrade it to openwrt for using captive portal. I am using coova-chilli for captive portal. I setup router with 2 ssid's one is for private use and other it will ask to login through captive portal for external users.

Everything is working fine, but the issue is after login through captive portal user can access the routers webpage and also able to ssh. I want to stop users to access router page and ssh as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found answer for my own question. Hopefully, this will be useful for
someone in the future. I made new network interface. Do cahnges in following files.
In /etc/config/network

```
config interface 'youfi'    
    option ifname 'eth2'  
    option force_link '1'  
    option type 'bridge'  
    option proto 'static'  
    option ipaddr '10.0.0.1'  
    option netmask '255.255.255.0'  
    option isolate '1'
```

In /etc/config/dhcp

```
config dhcp 'youfi'  
    option interface 'youfi'
    option start '50'
    option limit '200'
    option leasetime '1h'
```

In /etc/config/firewall

```
config zone
    option name 'youfi'
    option forward 'REJECT'
    option output 'ACCEPT'
    option network 'youfi'
    option input 'REJECT'

config forwarding
    option dest 'wan'
    option src 'youfi'

config rule
    option target 'ACCEPT'
    option proto 'tcp udp'
    option dest_port '53'
    option name 'youfi DNS'
    option src 'youfi'

config rule
    option enabled '1'
    option target 'ACCEPT'
    option name 'youfi DHCP'
    option src 'youfi'
    option proto 'udp'
    option dest_port '67-68'
```

In /etc/config/wireless

```
config wifi-iface
    option device 'radio0'
    option network 'youfi'
    option mode 'ap'
    option encryption 'none'
    option ssid 'abcxyz'
```

In /etc/config/chilli
Change in this line do br-lan to br-youfi

```
option dhcpif           br-lan
```

to

```
option dhcpif           br-youfi
```

and then

```
/etc/init.d/chilli stop
/etc/init.d/chilli start
```

It is working as I want.